# Model configuration: dynamically assign questions based on type of Location

Tags: django, django-models

I have an app where Locations can be added and a User can leave a review (5 star rating). This is already working.

What I'd like to do, is add Questions and Choices to the review. However, I'd like to make sure that only certain types of Questions are asked, depending on the type of Location.

So far I'm thinking of expanding the types of Location using a OneToOneField, which is very similar to the official docs example with a Restaurant and a Place having a OneToOneField relationship, and then further specifying that with a ManyToManyField for Category and SubCategory models.

However, what I'm struggling with, is how to add a Question to all types of a certain location.

What I currently, is that Questions have to be added on a place by place basis. Instead, what I'd like is to add a Question to all Restaurants (OneToOneField to Location) or maybe even to the Category (ManyToManyField to Restaurants).

What would be the best way forward? Do I need yet another model to hold the configuration of questions for a type of Location?

Also, unrelated note but can I have a class Question with attribute question? Or will this cause me grief down the road?

Thanks for any tips/advice in getting me further in this.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    questions = models.ManyToManyField('reviews.Question', blank=True)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    ...
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    primary_key=True,)

class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    RATING_STAR_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1 star'),
        (2, '2 star'),
        (3, '3 star'),
        (4, '4 star'),
        (5, '5 star'),
    )
    stars = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_STAR_CHOICES)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, null=True, blank=True,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```